# Spring Batch Process Questions

Tags: spring, spring-batch

2 questions on spring batch , Can someone please shed more light on this.

1) I have implemented `registerShutdownHook` in my spring batch project, but when I do kill my batch process it is not stopping immediately. It is waiting till the entire batch process is completed. Thats how it works?

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  final AbstractApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("\"com.lexisnexis.batch\",\"com.lexisnexis.rules\"");    
  appContext.registerShutdownHook();
  ...
}
```

Does it needs to stop all running batches and when we do kill with this `registerShutdownHook` code?

2) What is the best way to restart all stopped jobs?

Comment: How do you 'kill' your batch process?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, that's how it works. It's needed to close spring application context gracefully. Please check spring framework's [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-shutdown).
2. To restart your stopped job you need to invoke `jobOperator.restart(executionId)` or use `jobLauncher.run` with same parameters you used to start original job.